# upgrade to 14.04 only did half upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

When i tried upgrading to 14.04 from 13.10 it said it could only upgrade half, then i would have to upgrade the other half. well after the first half upgraded, it never mentioned to upgrade the other half. It will never update. It will say there are updates and I have a exclamation mark in the toolbar and i click install updates...nothing happens. when I use the updater it says its installing then it says all software is up to date and wont install anything but will continually say updates are available.

I tried to run "apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade" but got a bunch of errors. Here is the paste bin of the results. http://pastebin.com/3nTTib2C

I don't know what else to do a this point. I would love to avoid a clean install because I have a lot to backup and it will take me a while to backup everything manually. Thank you everyone for your help!

_-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I had to do a clean install. Restoring the PPAs didn't work. It kept retrieving the old PPAs again. Could not figure out any other way than a clean upgrade.

Comment: try cmdline `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: here was the results of that. same thing pretty much.  http://pastebin.com/yUr9UaQZ

Comment: access to the site blocked at my end!!!!! :(

Comment: will this site work for you?  http://sharetext.org/B8aF

Comment: You need to disable all the PPAs and extra repositories. Dupe of [How do I restore the default repositories?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

The (*actual*) issue here is that you have duplicate entries of the Google Chrome repos and are using repos from `raring` and `lucid`.

Start by opening up `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and you should see an entry for `archive.canonical.com`. Change the `raring` there to `trusty`. You should also see an entry for `plex.r.worldssl.net`. Unless you have it set to `lucid` for a very good reason (also assuming that you can still use the packages from that repo), change that to `trusty`.

Finally, you might see two entries for `dl.google.com`; if not, check to see if there are any files related to Google in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Remove one of the two entries. If there is one entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, *and* a Chrome-related file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, remove the one that's in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Run `sudo apt-get update` now.